# exporting data in json format

Tags: php, json

I am trying to export data from PhpMyAdmin to JSON format
This code works for `select lat,lng from googlemaps`, but does not for the `address` column
My code is:

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","googlemaps");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT lat,lng,`addr` FROM infos";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{

$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}


$fp = fopen('results01.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "{ \"tab\":  ");
fwrite($fp, json_encode($resultArray));
fwrite($fp, " }");
fclose($fp);
echo json_encode($resultArray);
//var_dump($resultArray);
?>
```

Screenshot of `infos` table:

[image: this is the data that i want to export]

Comment: Why did you put ` around `addr` in query?

Comment: we usually put it around the column name when we have spaces in it; i just add it to see if it s the problem
i just resolved the problem by adding before the SELECT query 
    mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

Comment: Great :) Glad you solved it. You can explain what you did in answer to your own question and accept the answer

Comment: Thaank you i just posted the answer but i can t accept it till 2 days since i am new here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution it s actually adding this before the select query :

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
$sql = "SELECT lat,lng,`addr` FROM infos";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{......}
```